# Did John Tesh win 6 Emmys and an AP award for investigative journalism?

Tags: history

The [Wikipedia page for John Tesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Tesh) lists him as having won 6 Emmy's and an "AP award for investigative journalism". This claim is repeated on numerous sites. I cannot find a primary source for any of these claims though. Respectable outlets repeat the claim that he was won an Emmy, e.g. [for his score for the 1987 Tour de France](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/1995/09/15/john-tesh-dont-laugh/09deb477-2c13-4e5a-91aa-22ca8838c6b7/). Searching through the Emmy archives in the years around 1987 don't surface this award though. Can anyone find any primary references for any of these awards?

Comment: Would [Tesh's own website](https://web.archive.org/web/20080410034843/http://tesh.com/ittrium/visit?path=A1x97x1y1xa5x1x76y1x3e70x1x65y1x40fx1x65) count as a primary source? It's cited on the linked Wikipedia page.

Comment: For supposedly being a major award, it seems very hard to find a complete list of Sports Emmy winners for 1987.  The Emmy site itself doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: @F1Krazy I would say no...one could imagine a desire to embellish on his own website.

Comment: @PhysicalMathematics it’s not a primary reference simply because John Tesh is not the person who decides who wins an Emmy. His self-report of having won an Emmy is therefore a secondary reference. That would be true even if he were reporting on someone else winning an Emmy. (And the fact that he’s reporting on himself means it’s not a _credible_ reference from the point of view of a skeptic, which I think is what you’re trying to say.)

Comment: Funnily enough, AP's reporting on Tesh doesn't mention the AP award https://apnews.com/article/d42d1b403ce8475a8d28fe5962c860d1 The only AP award for investigative journalism listed on wikipedia is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malcolm_Law_Investigative_Reporting_Award but doesn't have a list of winners.

Comment: Documentation of events before the WWW can be (relatively) difficult ... if not possible sitting at home with your computer, then you may have to: contact someone; go to an archive in person; interview witnesses yourself; etc...

Comment: [Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/artist/59B2CHEMh1to8diq0jB92r) lists some details on the alleged awards (called "music Emmys" by some sources) but the trail runs cold there as far as I found.

Comment: If the award is the "Malcolm Law Investigative Journalism Award", that makes the statement interesting in a number of ways. The award is only for journalism *in the state of Tennessee*, which makes it more probable that he won it (Tesh's early career was in Tennessee) but also most less prestigious. It may be a bit weaselly for Tesh to make the claim of an investigative journalism award without saying it's only a state award, but it's a pretty minor amount of weaselling.

Comment: According to [this source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/tv/1986/12/21/theres-more-to-etsunlikely-co-host-than-meets-the-eye/477114c0-80a4-4b9e-9877-98c2037d82da/) he won two NY-Area Emmys in 1977, although I could only verify one of them in [their archive](https://www.nyemmys.org/the-ny-emmy-awards-winners/). The ceremony in question is the [21st installment](https://www.nyemmys.org/media/files/files/3267e481/nyemmyawards21.pdf).

Comment: There is also AP's internal [Oliver S. Gramling Awards](https://www.ap.org/press-releases/2022/ap-announces-winners-of-2022-oliver-s.-gramling-awards), but this seems irrelevant here